# sphinx search without space not working in magento

Tags: magento, sphinx

sphinx search not working without space between product name. for example if my product name is "LINEN BLAZER" and i am trying to search like 
"LINENBLAZER" result is not showing. can anybody resolve my issue or give me any suggesion to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reall mangic solution to this. Sphinx can't know how to split words.

But there is
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/01/29/a-new-tool-in-the-trunk-wordbreaker/

which potentially can be used to build a system that can 'autosplit' works for searching. Don't know anyone used it with the magento plugin

Comment: is that necessary to save the word into the text file or should we go for mysql regular expression query. ?

Comment: Umm, neither of them. Or rather dont see how either of them would help. Will be a complex system to take advantage of wordbreaker, will need some experimentation to get to work.